# Random function doesn't work within discord bot

Tags: python-3.x, random, python-asyncio, discord, discord.py

I wanted to get a lsit containing an amount of randomly generated digits between 0-9, and I used:

```
for a in range(2**power):
    tree[levels-1].append(random.randint(0,9))
```

which outputs something like: [0, 3, 2, 4, 3, 9, 4, 8] When used in isolation in another program.

However when I tried to do this within a function within a command in a discord bot:

First command:

```
@client.command()
async def game():
    tree = await maketree(4)
```

Function within command:

```
def maketree(levels):
   for a in range(2**power):
       tree[levels-1].append(random.randint(0,9))
```

I get the error:
'Command' object has no attribute 'randint'

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. It's very likely that you reassigned to `random` at some point in your program, and it's impossible to know without a [mcve].

Comment: no need for a loop. use random.choices() with a range like so: `oneHundredRandomIntsBetween0and9inclusive = random.choices(range(10),k=100)`

Comment: should `maketree` be async as well to make it awaitable in th first place?

Answer (score 1):

You named a command `random`, which disposed of your reference to the `random` module.  You can rename that command such that it can still be called using `!random`

```
@bot.command(name="random", ...)
async def random_(...):
    ...
```